# What is Mindedness(chitt ekaagrata) based on Hinduism?

Tags: worship, idols, mind

There are many ways to find yourself, As per Hinduism **Mindedness(chitt ekaagrata)** is one way to find yourself.

I've also read that using of **Mindedness** with proper practice and Idol Worship, Which makes our life better as like became more concentrated, more active etc.

So there is any method of how to do that and how that helps.

Comment: Wait... Is it mindfulness or Mindedness? If mindedness = mindfulness then Mindedness is to being aware of surroundings & aware of what is happening in the mind. It's not exactly EkAgratA. When you start seeing mind then something unveils which isn't mind because mind can't see itself, There must be something superior to see the mind. Mindfulness which is to see the things as they are (including mind) trains to separate mind from self identification. When you separate both body & mind from your self identification - what finally remain finally is Shiva, your real nature.

Comment: Related: [Concentration meditation vs awareness meditation](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17211/1049)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Patanjali Yoga-Sutras  the word Dharana is used to denote mindfulness or chitt ekagrata as desired by you - Mindedness with proper practice and Idol Worship Patanjali is defining this phenomena as.

> देशबन्धः चित्तस्य धारणा ॥1॥
>
> deśa-bandhaḥ cittasya dhāraṇā || [**Yoga Sutras 3.1**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-sutras-with-vedanta-commentaries/d/doc115517.html)  ||
>
> Concentration (dharana) is holding the mind within a center of
>   spiritual consciousness in the body, or **fixing it on some divine form,**
>   either within the body or outside it.

---

3.1 [**Concentration**](http://www.swamij.com/yoga-sutras-30103.htm#3.1) (dharana) is the process of holding or fixing the attention of mind onto one object or place, and is the sixth of the eight rungs. (deshah bandhah chittasya dharana)

---

In order to achieve this concentration, we must calm and purify our minds. Patañjali now tells us how to do this. He prescribes the mental attitude we should take toward our neighbours in this world.

> मैत्री करुणा मुदितोपेक्षाणांसुखदुःख पुण्यापुण्यविषयाणां भावनातः
>   चित्तप्रसादनम् ॥33॥
>
> maitrī karuṇā mudito-pekṣāṇāṃ-sukha-duḥkha puṇya-apuṇya-viṣayāṇāṃ
>   bhāvanātaḥ citta-prasādanam ||[**Yoga Sutras 1.33**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-sutras-with-vedanta-commentaries/d/doc115487.html)||
>
> Undisturbed calmness of mind is attained by cultivating friendliness
>   toward the happy, compassion for the unhappy, delight in the virtuous,
>   and indifference toward the wicked.

Concentration (3.1) comes from attention and means that the attention is focused on one object, though the concentration may be interrupted, and is thus temporary. There is still an observer, who is doing the process of observing, and an object that is being observed.

The centers of spiritual consciousness here referred to are the seven lotuses (II, 49-50). **In order to concentrate, you must first fix your mind upon the Inner Light within one of these lotuses, as your teacher directs. Or you may concentrate upon the form of your Chosen Ideal, trying to visualize that form either within a lotus or outside your own body altogether.**

---

Now here Patanjali is telling us about another kind of concentration ,where there are no thoughts in mind , or consciousness contains no object. This can be achieved through non attachment and practicing  not to let any thought wave getting being generate in our mind constantly.

> विरामप्रत्ययाभ्यासपूर्वः संस्कारशेषोऽन्यः ॥ [**Yoga Sutras
>   1.18**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-sutras-with-vedanta-commentaries/d/doc115481.html) ॥
>
> virāma-pratyaya-abhyāsa-pūrvaḥ saṃskāra-śeṣo-'nyaḥ ||18||
>
> The other kind of concentration is that 'in which the consciousness
>   contains no object—only subconscious impressions, which are like burnt
>   seeds. It is attained by constantly checking the thought-waves through
>   the practice of non-attachment.

---

And here is the brief procedure.

> 3.1 comes from attention and means that the attention is focused on one object, though the concentration may be interrupted, and is thus
>   temporary. There is still an observer, who is doing the process of
>   observing, and an object that is being observed.
>
> After sitting in either Padmasana (lotus position) or any other Asana,
>   and after concentrating the sight to the tip of the nose and after
>   controlling both the hands and legs, meditate on the letter ‘Aum’ with
>   a concentrated mind. If one continuously meditates on Parameshwara,
>
> If we sit in an asana and continuously practice, the bindu will cease
>   from going down. Without Pooraka and Rechaka, the Prana would stand in
>   Kumbhaka for a very long time. You would hear different types of
>   sound. The nectar will start flowing from the place of the moon.
>   Hunger and thirst will cease. Mind would get concentrated on the ever
>   flowing bliss. The four steps for this are Mantra Yoga, Laya Yoga,
>   Hatha Yoga and Raja Yoga.